# Custom RecordType Selection based on criteria

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to restrict the user from selecting the Opportunity recordtypes based on account record type but the user profile needs to have access to all the recordtypes.Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

On each profile, you remove all the RecordTypes being available from the Opportunity object, that will remove the record type selection screen when you click on New Opportunity. They will still have access to all records as per your defined security, the only thing is they will never be able to choose a specific record types.

So now you create a workflow on creation of the Opportunity with a field update and based on your criteria, assign the right record type to the opportunity. You will probably need one workflow for each record type.

[image]

Otherwise, if you have a developer you can probably do that on before insert. Now it will depend on how complex is your business logic, sometimes it easier by code than workflow.

Comment: Problem user should be able to choose more than one opportunity recordtype for the different type of account recordtype .It is not one to one.

Comment: Oh my bad, just read your question again, an example might be good to illustrate your scenario. But I can tell you already you can't do what you are trying to achieve with out of the box functionality. The only thing you might do is to have some validation rules (If Account RT == RT1 && Oppty RT = RT2, then throw error), but in terms of visual you will always see all record types then.